# How can I delete a line and add other new lines using the erased as a pointer in a file with php?

Tags: php, file

My question is how I can point to a line according to its content in this case would be ";*" delete this line and where was this line continue writing

Input text:

```
[SIP34]
include => portabilidad

[SIP85]
include => portabilidad

;*

[SIP51]
include => portabilidad
```

This is the code I added the lines at the end of the file:

```
$file = fopen('C:\archivos\extensions.conf', 'a+');
while(!feof($file)) {
  $line = fgets($file);
  if (stristr($line ,';*')) {
    fwrite($file,  PHP_EOL.'[new]'.PHP_EOL);
    fwrite($file, 'include => portabilidad'.PHP_EOL);
    fwrite($file,  PHP_EOL.';*'.PHP_EOL);
  }
}
fclose($file);
```

Output text with my code:

```
[SIP34]
include => portabilidad

[SIP85]
include => portabilidad

;*

[SIP51]
include => portabilidad

[new]
include => portabilidad

;*
```

Output expected:

```
[SIP34]
include => portabilidad

[SIP85]
include => portabilidad

[new]
include => portabilidad

;*

[SIP51]
include => portabilidad
```

it is eliminated "; *" and it is replaced with "[new]" then it continues writing and putting the respective mark to be able to continue adding

Output with "r+":

```
[SIP34]
include => portabilidad

[SIP85]
include => portabilidad

;*

[new]
include => portabilidad

;*

[SIP51]
include => portabilidad
```

Comment: `a+ ... In this mode, fseek() only affects the reading position, writes are always appended.` from [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) Try `r+`.

Comment: it works but not at all, how can I do to eliminate the ";*" leftover now leaves me with two ";*"

Comment: One was there, and you are writing one other...

Comment: update the post with the result of r+

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easier to read, replace and write:

```
$new  = '[new]'.PHP_EOL.'include => portabilidad'.PHP_EOL.';*';
$file = 'C:\archivos\extensions.conf';
file_put_contents($file, str_replace(';*', $new, file_get_contents($file)));
```

Comment: sry, I was focus